# Не выводится список аудио файлов

Tags: android

Есть метод, который выводит список аудио файлов в RecyclerView. На Android версий 4,5,6,9 в список ничего не выводится (на Android 10 нормально). Проверялось все на виртуальных устройствах. Почему так?

```
private void parseAllAudio() {

    songList = new ArrayList<>();

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    if(resolver!=null) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor!=null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "find "+cursor.getCount()+" hidden folders");
        }

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //String path;
            File file;
            do {
                file = new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA))); //Получаем файл

                //Если файл найден
                if (file.exists()) {

                    Date createDate = new Date(file.lastModified());

                    if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains("myaudio")) {
                        songList.add(new Song(
                                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID))
                                ,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE))
                                ,getFileSize(file)
                                ,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA))
                                ,createDate
                        ));
                    }
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну понятно же, что одно из условий не проходит. Под дебаггером посмотрите или в лог выведите содержимое колонки `data` - думаю станет понятно что не так. Вообще Андроид несколько раз менял отношение к этой колонке - и что там на конкретном девайсе неизвестно (может быть путь к файлу, контент-uri или вообще `null`)

Comment: Разрешения есть. Не понимаю в чем проблема. На реальном устройстве с Android 6 тоже не отобразился список, хотя файлы есть

Comment: В логи выводится "find 0 hidden folders". Вроде бы условие "cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()" не срабатывает.

Comment: В этом условии cursor.moveToFirst() false. Но не понимаю почему. Выше вызываю cursor.moveToFirst(); не помогает.

Comment: Это значит курсор пустой - ничего не найдено. Файлы "вручную" добавлялись? Чтобы `MediaStore` их видел, он должен добавить их в свою базу. Не знаю как это сделать не программно. Если программно - то нужно добавить их через того же контент-провайдера или "отсканировать": https://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/

Comment: Файлы создавались из другого активити по кнопки "Запись" происходила запись в папку myaudio. Только для версий Android >= 10 запись шла в папку Music/myaudio, а для версий ниже в корень устройства в папку myaudio. Но тут Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); ищутся везде

Comment: А на кой вам провайдер, если вы их туда сами записали? - можно же просто получить список файлов в этой папке старым добрым `File.listFiles()`

Comment: А что если пользователь вручную перенесет файлы в другую папку? По этим соображениям я думала использовать способ, который у меня в методе.

Comment: Его проблемы, по-моему. Я уже писал выше - отсканируйте их после записи, чтобы `MediaStore ` добавил их к себе в базу, или записывайте тем же способом, что и для 10+, тогда сможете найти их через провайдера

Comment: Попробую, спасибо.

Comment: а какие targetSdkVersion и compileSdkVersion ?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 30 и targetSdkVersion 30. Совет @woesss помог.